# Powershell remove-item not working

Tags: powershell

Why is

```
dir E:\Music -File -Exclude *.mp3 -Recurse | foreach {del $_.FullName}
```

not working? I tested all the possibilities I could think of and it is still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, i used the following to fix it:

```
dir E:\Music -File -Exclude *.mp3 -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Comment: The cool thing here is that you don't need the `foreach` because `Remove-Item` will take streamed input objects.

Comment: This worked for me but I still don't understand why `Remove-Item -recurse` doesn't work. I had a script where `dir -recurse` returned several files on subfolders but `del -recurse` did not delete them. I change that to `dir -recurse | del` and that works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The command looks ok and should work. Do you get any output if you remove the pipe to foreach-object? Are you using PowerShell v3? Give this a try, do you get WhatIf messages?

```
dir E:\Music -File -Exclude *.mp3 -Recurse | del -WhatIf
```

Comment: if i remove the pipe, i do get output. i am using powershell v3. the first time i tried your script and whatif messages were generated. i removed the whatif and checked but no files were deleted. i ran your script as you wrote it again, and this time no more whatif messages were generated. i completely dont get this behavior. thank you.

Comment: It's hard to say the cause, your command and mine worked for me the first time I used each.

Comment: Can you try on other test files?

Comment: i created a new folder 'New Folder', created another new folder inside, in the new folder created 64 new text files, and made copied of the second level new folder 8 times. i changed the extensions of one text file in the each of the first two second level folders to .test, and ran my original command like this: dir 'E:\New Folder' -File -Exclude *.test -Recurse | foreach {del $_.FullName}. surprisingly, it worked. i still cant see whats wrong with my original command...

Comment: wait, i changed my command to "dir E:\Music -File -Exclude *.mp3 -Recurse -Hidden | foreach {del $_.FullName}" and stuff like "Cannot remove item E:\Music\Death Cab For Cutie\Something About Airplanes\AlbumArtSmall.jpg: Not Enough permission to 
perform operation." appeared, so i changed it to "dir E:\Music -File -Exclude *.mp3 -Recurse -Hidden | foreach {del $_.FullName -Force}" then it worked! seriously, get-childitem doesnt normally list hidden objects? that was one bad decision to make at redmond.

Comment: anyways, is there a switch in dir that automatically lists ALL childitems? it would be so much more convenient

Comment: apparently thats not the case, the recurse switch does not list hidden children by default. thanks for being so helpful and discussing so throughly with me anyways

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13902/discussion-between-idiotretard-and-shay-levy)

Answer (score 2):

See Example 4 from the following command

```
 get-help remove-item -Examples
```

"Because the Recurse parameter in this cmdlet is faulty..."

would be my guess.